# Signalize thread to start specific function

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I want to split some CPU intensive jobs to multiple threads. I want to make a thread pool with, let's say, 4 threads.

I want to know very fast ways to do following:

1. Check if one thread is free for receiving processing
2. Signalize one thread to start specific function
3. Wait for all the threads to finish their jobs

This should be as fast as possible. I use C++ in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. Any Win7/VS2010 specific solution would be preferred if it's faster than portable approach.

EDIT: 
I found on MSDN this sample:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946(v=vs.85).aspx

Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: The example code creates threads every time and waits for them to terminate. That's not going to be high-performance :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff from the Boost thread library is pretty fast. You can start 4 threads that end up waiting for a boost::condition_variable. In the main thread you can add stuff to a task-queue and then call boost::condition_variable::notify_one in order to start one free thread, if any. As soon as one of the working threads is notified, it takes stuff out of the task queue and continues to do so until the queue is empty. In order to wait for the task queue to finish, let the thread that makes the task queue empty call boost::condition_variable::notify_all and wait in the main thread for that signal. Obviously you need to protect the shared data for this stuff with a mutex.

This technique works fine if you have medium to large size tasks and several thousand or less should execute in a second. I don't have experience with smaller tasks using this technique.

The parallel patterns library (PPL) is really good at that stuff too, it does a lot of stuff for you, but you don't have as much control. It's Windows only, but that seems to be fine with you. ;)

---

EDIT: Your link seems to be a good solution. Using the WINAPI is often the fastest thing  you can do, since other APIs are usually build upon it. The WINAPI does not, however, provide very good abstraction. Thus I would prefer PPL, futures, etc. to perform tasks like that. How big are your tasks? If they take more than a few milliseconds, then you shouldn't worry about the api you're using, since that's not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

First way: [Asynchronous Procedure Calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681951.aspx).

Another way: [I/O Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx), which can be used for your task.

Comment: I/O completion port queues are aven slower than a Window Message Queue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Visual C++ specific Thread Pools however I've heard about existance of some `ppl.h`. there an unofficial [`boost threadpool`](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) that I've use one. and just as all other boost It compiles well in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

try tbb

```
class SimpleTask: public tbb::task {

public:
    SimpleTask(const char *c ) {}
    task* execute() {
        //do task
        return 0;
    }
};
//execute tasks and wait
    tbb::task_scheduler_init init(50);//initialize pool
        tbb::task_list list;

        for(int i=0;i<30;i++){//create 30 task

            list.push_back(*new(tbb::task::allocate_root()) SimpleTask());
        }

tbb::task::spawn_root_and_wait(list);//execute and wait for all task or call spawn without wait
```